# Apple App Id: Handing over an App ID

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I accidently created an app id for my private account something like com.example.companyname. Unfortunalty the company would like to use this app id. I did know that you cannot change an app id. Therefore I'm wondering if it is possible to transfer this app id to thier account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those app id's will always be associated with the account who has created them.

The best way to "transfer" an application from one account to another is to keep the same application name (that the user sees in their iPhone app), but delete the app from your private (or personal) account and then upload the app into the new account *with a different application (or bundle) ID*.

Even if it's just a subtle change in characters, it should be okay for submission (as long as the original app on your private account is pulled).

Comment: I'm not shure if I did understand this correctly. I just want to make shure that the name of the app under the icon and in the app store is called "companyname" signed with the developer account of companyname although the name com.example.companyname belongs now to my private account.

Comment: right... instead of an app named "CompanyApp" with a app ID of "com.example.companyname" in your account, submit the app under the company's account with a name of "CompanyApp" (i.e. same name) but an app ID of "com.companyname.CompanyApp".  Makes more sense now?